# How to start development on existing java web application

Tags: java, web-applications, struts

I come from an Asp.Net development background and am very comfortable there. I was asked to support an existing Java Web Application w/ struts and am able to figure most of it out with my Asp.Net knowledge and my android development experience. However, I'm having a really simple but stupid problem.

All i have is the website as it exists on the server, no source project to work from. The folder on the server contains both .java and .class files, but the folder doesn't just import into netbeans as a recognized project.

What's the easiest way to get the site imported into some sort of IDE (I can work w/ eclipse too if netbeans isn't recommended), and get it to compile so I can deploy some updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not be easy to answer fully to your question here. But we should be able to achieve that by steps :)

Here i will speak for eclipse. But it is only because i'm not familiar with netbeans.

First of all create a clean "dynamic web project" under eclipse (using a J2EE enabled eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). 
Then :

- copy your sources files in "Java Resources"
- copy the rest of your application (without the class files) in WebContent

In order to test your application localy you will need a local server. Tomcat can be integrated easily in eclipse.

Comment: Ok, I will try this, and let you know the results...just to clarify though, currently the source files (.java) are in the same folders with the class files (.class), so I will need to separate those by hand to get this to compile?

Comment: Basically I had to copy source files into the proper directory (for netbeans I had to place them in the src\java folder) and then fix some dependency issues. It was a hassle, but that seems yo be the path thats working.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you shouldn't have to (re)construct a project from a deployed web-app; the project should have been kept in version control. Source code isn't usually deployed to the server, either, but if it's been done in this case, you're in luck.

I would just make a new web project in NetBeans and manually move the .java files into it, along with the other resources (except for the .class files).

Comment: I wish this project was in version control. It's the first thing I am going to do to the project, but for now I am trying to reconstruct it from the raw folders on the server. But, you mention to move the .java files without the .class files. Do I need to put the .java files anywhere special for NetBeans, or is leaving them in the WEB-INF\classes folder fine?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use eclipse, and the source files are already in the war file as you say. You can import the war file directly into eclipse as project.

file -> import -> war file or existing project into workspce or filesystem (Several other options exists)

Comment: here is the interesting part, it does not appear that this project was put into a war file. It's just the raw folders sitting on the server with both .class and .java files in the WEB-INF/classes folder

Comment: war file is a zip file of all those you are telling. You can still use those files to create a war or directly use them to import into eclipse.